# Not able to click if frame is away from main view frame in android react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Not able to click if frame is away from main view frame in android react-native

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
      <View
        style={{
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          backgroundColor: '#FFF',
          margin: 50,
          // ...Shadow.LARGE,
          shadowColor: '#000000',
          shadowOpacity: 1,
          shadowRadius: 16,
          elevation: 20,
          zIndex: 1,
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: -25,
            left: 0,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            zIndex: 100,
          }}
         onPress={()=>{console.log('Pressed')}}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
```

=> If touchable button is away from main view then I am not able to click. It any way to I will able to click black button full frame.

Thanks[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0):

[image]Your problem is not clear. But I think you need to click touchable opacity. For that you can simply define onPress() function to touchable opacity.

```
<TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: -25,
            left: 0,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            zIndex: 100,
          }}
            onPress={()=>{console.log('Pressed')}}
        />
```

Your Code is working I think.

Comment: onPress is working but this is only click position in view area. Away from view area not click. This is issue.

On click arrow area is work because this is in main view. but in click "not click" area then click is not working.

Comment: Your Code is working I think. Check the image I have added. It took when I pressed the touchable opacity.

Comment: Button click working in iOS but android this is not working. Button is click in top area only. out of main view frame button not clickable.